# R plotly boxplots overwriting with numerical labels

Tags: r, plotly

I've found an issue with trying to use plotly under R to generate a boxplot, grouped by a variable which is numeric (and or numeric coerced to character):

```
library(plotly)

colors <- c("red","blue","green","pink","brown")
data.in <- data.frame(Age=25*rnorm(100)+50, IMD=sample(5,100,replace=TRUE))
fig <- plot_ly(data=data.in[data.in$IMD == "1",], y=~Age, type="box", color=I(colors[1]),name="1 - least")
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(data=data.in[data.in$IMD == "2",], y=~Age, type="box", color=I(colors[2]),name="2")
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(data=data.in[data.in$IMD == "3",], y=~Age, type="box", color=I(colors[3]),name="3")
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(data=data.in[data.in$IMD == "4",], y=~Age, type="box", color=I(colors[4]),name="4")
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(data=data.in[data.in$IMD == "5",], y=~Age, type="box", color=I(colors[5]),name="5 - most")
fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = "Age"),
                      xaxis = list(title = "IMD"),
                      boxgap = 0.1, boxgroupgap=0)
```

This code when used with a column that isn't numeric correctly gives a boxplot with side-by-side boxes and the correct labels. However, the previous code gives this:

[image: Bugged box plot]

It seems to plot the first plot at location 0 (and not 1), and overwrites the box at 4 with the box with the "5" label.

I have tried this on R v 4.2.2 (on MacOS 13.4) with plotly 4.10.1 and ggplot2 3.4.2 and on R v 4.0.2 (on x86_64) with plotly 4.10.2 and ggplot2 3.4.2, and get similar results.

Firstly, is this a bug with how plotly deals with numbers-as-characters for labels (the labels at the bottom are numeric and are not the labels I have given them), and secondly, is there a way of specifying where the boxes are plotted manually, so I can shift that on 0 to 1 and that which should be on 5 over to 5 rather than overplotting at 4?

Comment: I should also point out that the colours have to be specified to match previous plots using these categories - not specifying the traces individually doesn't have this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird. But one possible fix would be to map your numeric column on `x`:

```r
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)

colors <- c("red", "blue", "green", "pink", "brown")
data.in <- data.frame(Age = 25 * rnorm(100) + 50, IMD = sample(5, 100, replace = TRUE))
plot_ly(data = data.in[data.in$IMD == 1, ], x = ~IMD, y = ~Age, type = "box", color = I(colors[1]), name = "1 - least") %>%
  add_trace(data = data.in[data.in$IMD == 2, ], x = ~IMD, y = ~Age, type = "box", color = I(colors[2]), name = "2") %>%
  add_trace(data = data.in[data.in$IMD == 3, ], x = ~IMD, y = ~Age, type = "box", color = I(colors[3]), name = "3") %>%
  add_trace(data = data.in[data.in$IMD == 4, ], x = ~IMD, y = ~Age, type = "box", color = I(colors[4]), name = "4") %>%
  add_trace(data = data.in[data.in$IMD == 5, ], x = ~IMD, y = ~Age, type = "box", color = I(colors[5]), name = "5 - most") %>%
  layout(
    yaxis = list(title = "Age"),
    xaxis = list(title = "IMD"),
    boxgap = 0.1, boxgroupgap = 0
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I'd missed the x=~ construction to fix the x location, but it's odd that it affects when the label is numeric (and numeric-as-character) but not when it's character